# Derivative of: $ \frac{1}{\frac{10}{x}-0.1}$

Tags: linear-algebra

For a question in economics I need to derive the short run supply function. This is done by taking the derivative of the SRC function. The SRC function I have got is:
$$
 \dfrac{1}{\dfrac{10}{x}-0.1}
$$

We have done an example like this in class: $\dfrac{x^2}{16}$ has the derivative $\dfrac{x}{8}$, this example was quite easy. I hope you can help me.

Comment: does you function simplify to $\frac{10x}{100-x}?$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you mean, $f(x)=\frac{1}{(\frac{10}{x})-0.1}=\frac{1}{\frac{10-0.1x}{x}}=\frac{x}{10-0.1x}=\frac{u}{v}$

$f'(x)=\frac{vu'-uv'}{v^2}-\frac{10-0.1x-x(-0.1)}{(10-0.1x)^2}=\frac{10}{(10-0.1x)^2}$

Equivalently, you can write your expression as $f(x)=(10x^{-1}-0.1)^{-1}$ and use the chain rule to get

$f'(x)=-1(-10x^{-2})(10x^{-1}-0.1)^{-2}=\frac{10}{(10-0.1x)^2}$

Comment: Thanks for the reply, that makes a lot of sense. I'm now also looking into if I made any calculations mistakes in deriving the formula I gave at first. I'm afraid I'm having trouble mostly because the first formula isn't the right one.

Comment: Last commment: Everything checks out, I guess the teacher is just making it way more difficult than the examples he discussed in class. Thanks again for the help everyone!

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** Write your expression as $f(x) = (10x^{-1}-0.1)^{-1}$. The chain rule gives

$$f'(x) = (-1)(10x^{-1}-0.1)^{-2}\cdot(-10x^{-2})$$
Now simplify to whatever extent you desire.